# TSLint errors when trying to use newest version of ant design

Tags: typescript, antd, tslint

I am getting the following typescrit/tslint erros when trying to use version 4.21.7 of ant design within my Power BI custom visual:

```
ERROR in /node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts(17,11)
      TS1110: Type expected.

ERROR in /node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts(17,27)
      TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in /node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts(17,28)
      TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

ERROR in /node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts(18,1)
      TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

The code it is referencing to is the following, line 17 is ([key: `data-${string}`]: string;):

```
export interface InputProps extends Omit<RcInputProps, 'wrapperClassName' | 'groupClassName' | 'inputClassName' | 'affixWrapperClassName'> {
    size?: SizeType;
    disabled?: boolean;
    status?: InputStatus;
    bordered?: boolean;
    [key: `data-${string}`]: string;
}
```

My tslint.json looks like this, what am I missing?

```
{
    "extends": "tslint-microsoft-contrib/recommended",
    "rulesDirectory": [
        "node_modules/tslint-microsoft-contrib"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-relative-imports": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced similar issue and I upgraded the typescript in my package to 4.7.4 (latest version) and it worked

```
"typescript": "^4.7.4"
```

Comment: I ran into this same problem today. Upgraded to typescript 5.0.4 and then it worked :)